# Query or formula that takes data from different ranges

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, vlookup, google-query-language

I am looking for a single query (or formula) that can take data from different ranges and pull it together.

Example:

**range (name, class) and range (class, year) giving output (name, class, year).**

What is the best method?

It can be done by querying the first range, then adding vlookup to every row (to get data from second range).

Or a neater solution is to  get data from second range with a single formula, using vlookup nested in arrayformula.

```
Example:    =arrayformula(vlookup(J2:J, E3:G23, 2, false))
```

BUT I am looking for a single query or formula so the the final output can be ordered.

Example Sheet:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1njKqm9YwSP7iKnjzGkHxmYniwykrZRtxgGB2T-sf1pE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX({QUERY(A3:C,"select B,A where C is null"), IFNA(
VLOOKUP(QUERY(A3:C,"select A   where C is null"), E3:G23, {2, 3}, ))})
```

[image]

Comment: Very smooth. I eventually persuaded the formula to order the data, but the new formula seems even more bloated than before. `=query(INDEX({QUERY(A3:C1000,"select B,A where C is null"), IFNA(VLOOKUP(QUERY(A3:C1000,"select A where C is null"), E3:G23, {2, 3}, ))}),"where Col1 is not null order by Col4, Col3")`  Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: I have updated the example sheet. See Ordering tab.

Comment: @NewmanHard a bit shorter would be: `=SORT(INDEX({QUERY(A3:C1000,"select B,A where C is null"), IFNA(VLOOKUP(QUERY(A3:C1000,"select A where C is null"), E3:G23, {2, 3}, ))}), 4, 1, 3, 1)`

Comment: Love the way you used numbers with Sort rather than true/false.  I'm still fairly new at this, but I think we can shrink it further. Is Index still needed?    It seems to work OK without.  `=SORT({QUERY(A3:C1000,"select B,A where C is null"), IFNA(VLOOKUP (QUERY(A3:C1000, "select A where C is null"), E3:G23, {2, 3}, ))}, 4, 1, 3, 1)`